# Force focusrect in Checkbox, ComboBox or TButtonControl

Tags: delphi, checkbox, combobox, focus

I need to resolve a small and simple situation.

I have forms that the first active control is a CheckBox or ComboBox (TButtonControl). In some cases, when opening the form focusRect is assigned to the control, in other cases not.

**Just like to know if there is a way different than I force focusRect in a TButtonControl control.**

I tested several ways, but none is effective and works properly.

**Sample code used in my TCheckBox:**

```
Procedure TMyCheckBox.CMEnter(Var Message: TCMEnter);
Var
  LRect: TRect;
Begin
  Inherited;
  FillRect(Handle, LRect, Handle);
  DrawFocusRect(Handle, LRect);
End;
```

The cause of the problem focusRect is simulated as follows . If an application (.exe ) starts with the keyboard focusRect appears automatically, if run with the double click of the mouse, it is not displayed.

It's a Windows feature .

My intention is to force so that the focusRect always appears.

Thanks.

Comment: That code is not going to be of any use. You are trying stuff at random without first isolating and understanding the problem. That very seldom ends well. Why not first identify the real cause of the problem?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I completed the description. In theory, my code is correct. But don't work. This code is only sample to ilustrate situation.

Comment: Sertac Akyuz.
You are right. My question is the same as mentioned issue . Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: The code that you presented in the question is categorically not correct. You should not be attempting to draw outside of a paint cycle.

Comment: @Delphi - No problem. David's comment is probably the answer to your actual question however.